# Flash Alpha Value of Color

Tags: java, alpha

In my Java Game, I have a method named update() which is called about 60 times a second.

With this, I am adding 3 to an alpha value for a colour each time it's called. But, I want it to keep on adding, then when it gets to 255, start subtracting, so the colour is flashing in and out. How could I achieve this?

EDIT:
I just found a solution.

```
int alpha = 0;
int alphaB = -1;

if(alpha == 255) { // check alpha doesn't exceed limit
    alpha = 250;
} else if(alpha == 0) { // check alpha doesn't go below 0
    alpha = 5;
} else {
    if(alphaB < alpha) {
        alpha += 10;
        alphaB += 10;
    } else if(alphaB > alpha) {
        alpha -= 10;
        alphaB -= 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep a counter using `long`, take the modulus, you don't have to worry about overflow as it will increase by 60 per second and your code needs to run for `292471208678` years before overflow.

```
long alphacntr = 0;
....
public void update(){
alphacntr += 3;
int alpha = alphacntr%256;
....
}
```